# Why is my attempt to override bootstrap nav-link class not working in next.js?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, next.js

In the following segment of code I need to override bootstrap .nav-link.active values.

```
<li className="nav-item">
    <a
       className={`${styles.navLink} nav-link`}
       role="tab"
       data-toggle="tab"
       href="#tab-1"
    >
       LATEST PRODUCTS
    </a>
</li>
```

The css in the chrome developer tool looks like this:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #dee2e6 #dee2e6 #fff;
}
```

In next.js, I believe I cannot use .nav-link in the css file to override the values because selectors have to be camel case. So I am trying to use the following css to override values of .nav-link.active but it is not working.

```
.tabs .navTabs .navLink.active {
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an object properties with `[]` bracket notation instead of `.` dot notation.

```
className={styles['nav-link']}
```

Make sure that new styles have higher specificity than Bootstrap selectors.

[MDN: CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)